# Django: One template or two templates for different CSS?

Tags: css, django

I am making a website in Django for an online multiple-choice test. For each question, the question text is displayed on the webpage, together with a set of radio buttons for the possible answers, and a submit button. The user chooses on of the answers, and presses the button. Then, I want to give feedback to the user: A green "Correct", or a red "Incorrect", together with a button to retrieve the next question.

What is the best way to do this in Django? I could have two templates: one for the question, and one for the feedback, and each with one associated view function. For the question, I would pass variables for the question text, together with the text for the possible answers. This seems to work well. However, for the feedback, I would pass the text "Correct" or "Incorrect" as a variable, but how do I now change the CSS to set the text to be green if "Correct", and red if "Incorrect"? Would it be more sensible to have a separate template for the "Correct" case, and the "Incorrect" case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Django view should pass whether the answer is correct or not, i.e. a boolean.

Suppose the boolean variable in the template context is called `correct`; your template code could be something along these lines:

```
{% if correct %}
  // correct html markup in here
  <span class="correct">Correct!</span>
{% else %}
  // incorrect html markup in here
  <span class="incorrect">Woops, not correct!</span>
{% endif %}
```

The above should all go in the same template, i.e. one template only.